# Assign Releases to Reverse Release based on the balances

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables and need to assign the amounts based on the balances(releases) available.
Here the releases are only available for 20 so assign based on the availability

**RELEASE**

| PID | relDate | releaseAmount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| p1 | 1-May | 20 |

**Reverse Release**

| pid | revRelDate | revereseRelease |
| --- | --- | --- |
| p1 | 5-May | 15 |
| p1 | 6-May | 8 |

**Desired Output**

| pid | relDate | revRelDate | releaseAmount | revereseRelease |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p1 | 1-May | 5-May | 20 | 15 |
| p1 | 1-May | 6-May | 20 | 5 |

Tried Query:

```
WITH RELEASE AS (
    SELECT 'P1' PID, '2023-05-01' TRANSACTION_DATE, 23 RELEASE 
    FROM DUAL

) ,
REV_RELEASE AS (     
    SELECT 'P1' PID, '2023-05-05' TRANSACTION_DATE, 15 REV_RELEASE
    FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'P1' PID, '2023-05-06' TRANSACTION_DATE,  8 REV_RELEASE
    FROM DUAL)
SELECT  *,CASE
        WHEN RUNNING_TOTAL >= 0
        THEN
            CASE
                WHEN LEAD(RUNNING_TOTAL, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY PID ORDER BY TRANSACTION_DATE) >= 0
                THEN REV_RELEASE
                ELSE REV_RELEASE + RUNNING_TOTAL
            END
        ELSE 0
    END 
FROM (
            SELECT  a.RELEASE,b.*, SUM(RELEASE - REV_RELEASE) OVER (PARTITION BY a.PID ORDER BY b.TRANSACTION_DATE) AS RUNNING_TOTAL
              FROM
            RELEASE a FULL OUTER JOIN REV_RELEASE b
            ON a.PID=b.PID
)
```

Comment: Please don’t use images, add all information as editable text (formatted as tables for data) so that someone can copy it

Comment: @NickW- Sorry , I updated now

Comment: If it’s not a typo, how are you getting 5 in the desired output when the reverseRelease is 8? Assuming it is a typo, your desired result seems to be a straight join between the two tables

Comment: @NickW Only 20 was released. In `rev_release` there is 15 in the first row and then 8 in the second row which is the remaining 5 released plus 3 excess.

Answer (score 1):

You can use analytic functions to total the amounts and then `JOIN` the tables based on the cumulative totals:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(r.pid, rr.pid) AS pid,
       r.transaction_date AS rel_date,
       rr.transaction_date AS relRevDate,
       r.release AS releaseAmount,
       LEAST(
         rr.rev_release,
         rr.total_rev_release - r.total_release + r.release,
         r.total_release - rr.total_rev_release + rr.rev_release
       )
         AS rev_release
FROM   (
         SELECT pid,
                transaction_date,
                release,
                SUM(release)
                  OVER (PARTITION BY pid ORDER BY transaction_date, ROWNUM)
                  AS total_release
         FROM   RELEASE
       ) r
       FULL OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT pid,
                transaction_date,
                rev_release,
                SUM(rev_release)
                  OVER (PARTITION BY pid ORDER BY transaction_date, ROWNUM)
                  AS total_rev_release
         FROM   REV_RELEASE
       ) rr
       ON (   r.pid = rr.pid
          AND r.total_release - r.release < rr.total_rev_release
          AND r.total_release > rr.total_rev_release - rr.rev_release
          )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE RELEASE (pid, transaction_date, release) AS
  SELECT 'P1', DATE '2023-05-01',  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'P1', DATE '2023-05-03', 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'P1', DATE '2023-05-06',  4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'P1', DATE '2023-05-07',  4 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE REV_RELEASE (pid, transaction_date, rev_release) AS  
  SELECT 'P1', DATE '2023-05-05', 15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'P1', DATE '2023-05-06',  8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'P1', DATE '2023-05-07',  9 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| PID | REL_DATE | RELREVDATE | RELEASEAMOUNT | REV_RELEASE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | 2023-05-01 00:00:00 | 2023-05-05 00:00:00 | 5 | 5 |
| P1 | 2023-05-03 00:00:00 | 2023-05-05 00:00:00 | 20 | 10 |
| P1 | 2023-05-03 00:00:00 | 2023-05-06 00:00:00 | 20 | 8 |
| P1 | 2023-05-03 00:00:00 | 2023-05-07 00:00:00 | 20 | 2 |
| P1 | 2023-05-06 00:00:00 | 2023-05-07 00:00:00 | 4 | 6 |
| P1 | 2023-05-07 00:00:00 | 2023-05-07 00:00:00 | 4 | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/V8W6A8Fp)

Comment: @MT0- It does not work correctly if the release are multiple for the same PID.
if I update the release table in fiddle and then run the same , Release are not being split correctly.

--------------------------
CREATE TABLE RELEASE (pid, transaction_date, release) AS
  SELECT 'P1', DATE '2023-05-01', 5 FROM DUAL
   UNION
SELECT 'P1' , DATE '2023-05-03', 20 FROM DUAL

Answer (score 1):

You can use analytic function Sum() Over() with the windowing clause (... Rows Between ...) to get the running total. However, you would need nested Case expressions to handle the result for REV_RELEASE column cause there could be more rows in rev_release table ...

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e   D a t a :
    release AS 
       ( Select 'P1' "PID", Date '2023-05-01' "TRANSACTION_DATE", 20 "RELEASE"  From Dual 
       ),
    rev_release AS 
      ( Select 'P1' "PID", Date '2023-05-05' "TRANSACTION_DATE", 15 "REV_RELEASE" From Dual Union All
        Select 'P1' "PID", Date '2023-05-06' "TRANSACTION_DATE",  8 "REV_RELEASE" From Dual 
      )
```

```sql
--  M a i n    S Q L :
Select      r.PID, r.TRANSACTION_DATE "REL_DATE", rr.TRANSACTION_DATE "REV_REL_DATE", 
            r.RELEASE "REL_AMOUNT",
            CASE WHEN 
                  Case  When Sum(rr.REV_RELEASE) Over(Partition By r.PID Order By r.PID, rr.TRANSACTION_DATE
                                                    Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) > r.RELEASE
                        Then rr.REV_RELEASE - ( Sum(rr.REV_RELEASE) Over(Partition By r.PID Order By r.PID, rr.TRANSACTION_DATE
                                                                       Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) - r.RELEASE 
                                              )
                  Else rr.REV_RELEASE 
                  End < 0 Then 0 
            ELSE
                  Case  When Sum(rr.REV_RELEASE) Over(Partition By r.PID Order By r.PID, rr.TRANSACTION_DATE
                                                    Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) > r.RELEASE
                        Then rr.REV_RELEASE - ( Sum(rr.REV_RELEASE) Over(Partition By r.PID Order By r.PID, rr.TRANSACTION_DATE
                                                                       Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) - r.RELEASE 
                                              )
                  Else rr.REV_RELEASE 
                  End
            END "REV_RELEASE"
From        release r
Inner Join  rev_release rr ON(rr.PID = r.PID)
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
PID REL_DATE  REV_REL_DATE REL_AMOUNT REV_RELEASE
--- --------- ------------ ---------- -----------
P1  01-MAY-23 05-MAY-23            20          15
P1  01-MAY-23 06-MAY-23            20           5  */
```

...  with a bit more rows in sample data

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e   D a t a   2 :
    release AS 
       ( Select 'P1' "PID", Date '2023-05-01' "TRANSACTION_DATE", 20 "RELEASE"  From Dual Union All
         Select 'P2' "PID", Date '2023-05-01' "TRANSACTION_DATE", 20 "RELEASE"  From Dual
       ),
    rev_release AS 
      ( Select 'P1' "PID", Date '2023-05-05' "TRANSACTION_DATE", 15 "REV_RELEASE" From Dual Union All
        Select 'P1' "PID", Date '2023-05-06' "TRANSACTION_DATE",  8 "REV_RELEASE" From Dual Union All
        Select 'P1' "PID", Date '2023-05-07' "TRANSACTION_DATE",  8 "REV_RELEASE" From Dual Union All
        --
        Select 'P2' "PID", Date '2023-05-05' "TRANSACTION_DATE", 15 "REV_RELEASE" From Dual Union All
        Select 'P2' "PID", Date '2023-05-06' "TRANSACTION_DATE",  4 "REV_RELEASE" From Dual 
      )
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t   2 :
PID REL_DATE  REV_REL_DATE REL_AMOUNT REV_RELEASE
--- --------- ------------ ---------- -----------
P1  01-MAY-23 05-MAY-23            20          15
P1  01-MAY-23 06-MAY-23            20           5
P1  01-MAY-23 07-MAY-23            20           0
P2  01-MAY-23 05-MAY-23            20          15
P2  01-MAY-23 06-MAY-23            20           4   */
```

... you can, if needed, filter out rows with REV_RELEASE = 0 and do whatever you want with the rest of the resulting dataset.
Additionaly, if you have row(s) in release table with no matching rows in rev_release table and you want to show the release table row then just change inner join into left join in main sql.